# How do I Filter the PyQt QCombobox Items based on the text input?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qcombobox

I need a QCombox which Items are filtered based on the text input. If I set the QCombobox editable, the user can insert text and the QCompleter is automatically created. But the items are not filtered and I don’t want the user to add new Items.

Is there any possibility to add this functionality to the QCombobox?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this code, is something i used in a project of mine

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QComboBox, QApplication, QCompleter, QSortFilterProxyModel, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class ExtendedCombo( QComboBox ):
    def __init__( self,  parent = None):
        super( ExtendedCombo, self ).__init__( parent )

        self.setFocusPolicy( Qt.StrongFocus )
        self.setEditable( True )
        self.completer = QCompleter( self )

        # always show all completions
        self.completer.setCompletionMode( QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion )
        self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel( self )
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity( Qt.CaseInsensitive )



        self.completer.setPopup( self.view() )


        self.setCompleter( self.completer )


        self.lineEdit().textEdited[unicode].connect( self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString )
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.setTextIfCompleterIsClicked)

    def setModel( self, model ):
        super(ExtendedCombo, self).setModel( model )
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel( model )
        self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)

    def setModelColumn( self, column ):
        self.completer.setCompletionColumn( column )
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn( column )
        super(ExtendedCombo, self).setModelColumn( column )


    def view( self ):
        return self.completer.popup()

    def index( self ):
        return self.currentIndex()

    def setTextIfCompleterIsClicked(self, text):
      if text:
        index = self.findText(text)
        self.setCurrentIndex(index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QStandardItemModel()

    for i,word in enumerate( ['hola', 'adios', 'hello', 'good bye'] ):
        item = QStandardItem(word)
        model.setItem(i, 0, item)



    combo = ExtendedCombo()
    combo.setModel(model)
    combo.setModelColumn(0)

    combo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: THX, that's exactly what I was locking for.

Comment: It works as advertised. One minor issue I'm having is that when I filter the checkbox and pick one option by mouseclick, the currentIndexChanged signal isn't immediately sent, I have to click somewhere else first.

Comment: I'd also like to add that to get it working in PySide I had to initialize the completer with just a parent argument first and then set the model with `self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)`.  This was driving me nuts, but I finally figured it out while writing a question so I documented this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456460/qcombobox-with-autocompletion-works-in-pyqt4-but-not-in-pyside).

Answer (score 18):

searching inside the combobox. Finally a good solution. Thank you guys!! It helped me a lot.

And here is the adjusted code to PyQt5:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter, QComboBox

class ExtendedComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setEditable(True)

        # add a filter model to filter matching items
        self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())

        # add a completer, which uses the filter model
        self.completer = QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
        # always show all (filtered) completions
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)

        # connect signals
        self.lineEdit().textEdited.connect(self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)


    # on selection of an item from the completer, select the corresponding item from combobox 
    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        if text:
            index = self.findText(text)
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)
            self.activated[str].emit(self.itemText(index))


    # on model change, update the models of the filter and completer as well 
    def setModel(self, model):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModel(model)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(model)
        self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)


    # on model column change, update the model column of the filter and completer as well
    def setModelColumn(self, column):
        self.completer.setCompletionColumn(column)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn(column)
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModelColumn(column)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringListModel

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    string_list = ['hola muchachos', 'adios amigos', 'hello world', 'good bye']

    combo = ExtendedComboBox()

    # either fill the standard model of the combobox
    combo.addItems(string_list)

    # or use another model
    #combo.setModel(QStringListModel(string_list))

    combo.resize(300, 40)
    combo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for the nice answer, I had the same problem.
It works nicely, but forces you to supply an external model, which is unnecessary.
I extended the code to also work with the internal standard model already supplied by the combobox.
Also some cleanup and documentation has been done...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QCompleter, QComboBox, QSortFilterProxyModel

class ExtendedComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setEditable(True)

        # add a filter model to filter matching items
        self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())

        # add a completer, which uses the filter model
        self.completer = QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
        # always show all (filtered) completions
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)

        # connect signals
        self.lineEdit().textEdited[unicode].connect(self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)


    # on selection of an item from the completer, select the corresponding item from combobox 
    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        if text:
            index = self.findText(text)
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)


    # on model change, update the models of the filter and completer as well 
    def setModel(self, model):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModel(model)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(model)
        self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)


    # on model column change, update the model column of the filter and completer as well
    def setModelColumn(self, column):
        self.completer.setCompletionColumn(column)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn(column)
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModelColumn(column)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QStringListModel, QApplication

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    string_list = ['hola muchachos', 'adios amigos', 'hello world', 'good bye']

    combo = ExtendedComboBox()

    # either fill the standard model of the combobox
    combo.addItems(string_list)

    # or use another model
    #combo.setModel(QStringListModel(string_list))

    combo.resize(300, 40)
    combo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5):

Both answers posted are correct, however they have a small bug wherein filtering the options in the combobox by typing then clicking a selection doesn't cause an activation signal to fire. You can fix this by placing `self.activated[str].emit(self.itemText(index))` in `on_completer_activated`, on the line after `self.setCurrentIndex(index)`.

This fires an activated signal when you select an item from the completer, which contains the name of the item that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

if someone is interested: the same code for pyqt5

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    
    import sys
    
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QComboBox, QApplication, QCompleter
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel, Qt
    from PyQt5.Qt import QStringListModel
    
    
    class ExtendedComboBox(QComboBox):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(ExtendedComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
    
            self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
            self.setEditable(True)
    
            # add a filter model to filter matching items
            self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
            self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
            self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())
    
            # add a completer, which uses the filter model
            self.completer = QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
            # always show all (filtered) completions
            self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
            self.setCompleter(self.completer)
    
            # connect signals
            self.lineEdit().textEdited[str].connect(self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
            self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)
    
    
        # on selection of an item from the completer, select the corresponding item from combobox
        def on_completer_activated(self, text):
            if text:
                index = self.findText(text)
                self.setCurrentIndex(index)
                self.activated[str].emit(self.itemText(index))
    
    
        # on model change, update the models of the filter and completer as well
        def setModel(self, model):
            super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModel(model)
            self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(model)
            self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)
    
    
        # on model column change, update the model column of the filter and completer as well
        def setModelColumn(self, column):
            self.completer.setCompletionColumn(column)
            self.pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn(column)
            super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModelColumn(column)
    
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
        string_list = ['hola muchachos', 'adios amigos', 'hello world', 'good bye']
    
        combo = ExtendedComboBox()
    
        # either fill the standard model of the combobox
        combo.addItems(string_list)
    
        # or use another model
        #combo.setModel(QStringListModel(string_list))
    
        combo.resize(300, 40)
        combo.show()
    
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy.

```
index = your_combo.findText(searched_word, Qt.MatchFixedString)
if index >= 0:
    your_combo.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

You can also use Qt.MatchContain method.
visit https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html for more details.