# How to use ExtendedComboBox to work in ui file?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt-designer, qcombobox

I get exampel from this url: 
[How do I Filter the PyQt QCombobox Items based on the text input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827207/how-do-i-filter-the-pyqt-qcombobox-items-based-on-the-text-input)
An example is what I need, but I have a problem with running this in created ui file.
In ui file I have combobox.

When I use this:

```
  self.ui.comboBox = ExtendedComboBox()
  self.ui.comboBox.addItems(['test','test1','test3','test4'])
```

comboBox is empty and non activ.

When I use this:

```
  self.ui.comboBox = ExtendedComboBox()
  self.ui.comboBox.addItems(['test','test1','test3','test4'])
  self.ui.comboBox.show()
```

comboBox from ui file is still empty,but appears in a separate window properly runnin ExtendedComboBox.

**How to use ExtendedComboBox to work in ui file?**
Probably doing some stupid mistake

```
class ExtendedComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setEditable(True)
        # add a filter model to filter matching items
        self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())

        # add a completer, which uses the filter model
        self.completer = QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
        # always show all (filtered) completions
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)
        # connect signals
        self.lineEdit().textEdited[unicode].connect(self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)
    # on selection of an item from the completer, select the corresponding item from combobox
    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        if text:
            index = self.findText(text)
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)
    # on model change, update the models of the filter and completer as well
    def setModel(self, model):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModel(model)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(model)
        self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)
    # on model column change, update the model column of the filter and completer as well
    def setModelColumn(self, column):
        self.completer.setCompletionColumn(column)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn(column)
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModelColumn(column)

class CaDialogal(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_CaDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        **self.ui.comboBox = ExtendedComboBox()
        self.ui.comboBox.addItems(['test','test1','test3','test4'])
        #self.ui.comboBox.show()
        ##self.ui.comboBox.addItems(['test','test1','test3','test4'])**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace a widget from the ui file by simply assigning directly to it.

There are several ways of working around this, but probably the easiest for your case would be to use widget promotion. To do this, go back to Qt Designer and right-click on the combo-box you want to replace, and select "Promote to...". In the dialog, set "Promoted class name" to "ExtendedComboBox", and set "Header file" to the python import path for the module that contains this class (e.g. `myapp.mainwindow`). Then click "Add", and "Promote", and you will see the class change from "QComboBox" to "ExtendedComboBox" in the Object Inspector pane.

Now when you re-generate your ui module with pyuic, you should see that it uses your `ExtendedComboBox` class and there will be an extra line at the bottom of the file like this:

```
    from myapp.mainwindow import ExtendedComboBox
```

With that in place, all you need to do is:

```
    self.ui.comboBox.addItems(['test','test1','test3','test4'])
```

and hopefully everything should work as you intended.

Comment: I did all the steps, but appears normal comboBox:/

Comment: @user7172. What do you see in the file generated by pyuic? Do you see your `ExtendedComboBox` class in there? If not, you need to re-run pyuic.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake. Works just like I wanted. Many thanks:))