# PyQt4 QComboBox autocomplete without using setModel?

Tags: autocomplete, pyqt4, qcombobox

I have found several excellent examples of a PyQt4 QComboBox with autocomplete (e.g. [How do I Filter the PyQt QCombobox Items based on the text input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827207/how-do-i-filter-the-pyqt-qcombobox-items-based-on-the-text-input)), but they all use setModel and setSourceModel... etc.

Is it possible to create an autocomplete QComboBox in PyQt4 without using a model?

Comment: have you tried using setCompleter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using smitkpatel's comment... I found a setCompleter example which works.  It was posted by flutefreak at [QComboBox with autocompletion works in PyQt4 but not in PySide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24456460/259538).

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class AdvComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AdvComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setEditable(True)

        # add a filter model to filter matching items
        self.pFilterModel = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())

        # add a completer, which uses the filter model
        self.completer = QtGui.QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
        # always show all (filtered) completions
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QtGui.QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)

        self.setCompleter(self.completer)

        # connect signals

        def filter(text):
            print "Edited: ", text, "type: ", type(text)
            self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString(str(text))

        self.lineEdit().textEdited[unicode].connect(filter)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)

    # on selection of an item from the completer, select the corresponding item from combobox
    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        if text:
            index = self.findText(str(text))
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    combo = AdvComboBox()

    names = ['bob', 'fred', 'bobby', 'frederick', 'charles', 'charlie', 'rob']

    combo.addItems(names)
    combo.resize(300, 40)
    combo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```