# Filter with QComboBox C++

Tags: c++, qt, filter, qcombobox, qsortfilterproxymodel

I want to create an editable QComboBox which filters results according to the search query and updates the dropdown entries accordingly.

After reading [How do I Filter the PyQt QCombobox Items based on the text input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827207/how-do-i-filter-the-pyqt-qcombobox-items-based-on-the-text-input) I tried to implement something similar in C++.

But I can't store anything inside the QComboBox now. Even after adding new entries through addItem() the total count remains 0.

What is the reason for this and how do I insert entries inside the QComboBox with QSortFilterProxyModel?

Here is the relevant snippet of the code:

```
SearchBox = new QComboBox(this);
SearchBox->setEditable(true);

// Try adding a few entries and check if they persist after changing the model
SearchBox->addItem(QString("hi"));
SearchBox->addItem(QString("bye"));

int count = SearchBox->count();    // count = 2

ProxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel;
ProxyModel->setSourceModel(SearchBox->model());
ProxyModel->setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseSensitivity::CaseInsensitive);
SearchBox->setModel(ProxyModel);

// Check count again
count = SearchBox->count();    // count = 0     <- Why?

// Try adding new entries
SearchBox->addItem(QString("Hi again"));

count = SearchBox->count();    // count = 0  .. So new entries don't get stored


Completer = new QCompleter(ProxyModel,this);
Completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
SearchBox->setCompleter(Completer);


QObject::connect(SearchBox->lineEdit(), SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString)), ProxyModel, SLOT(setFilterFixedString(const QString)));
QObject::connect(Completer, SIGNAL(activated(const QString &)), this, SLOT(onCompleterActivated(const QString &)));
```

Comment: Don't pretend to answer, but for simpler task of filtering popup list by some query simple `QListView *view = SearchBox->view(); view->setRowHidden(row, condition);` worked like a charm. I wrote that just because for my simple task I spend more than 1h for googling and the most close solution I found in this question, and then figured out much simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `QStringListModel` to store items. Application crashes if proxy model have no items (if filter string filters out all items)(this needs further investigation - is this completer issue or combobox). This can be fixed by not applying such filter (`onTextChanged(QString text)` slot). Completer completes input if theres only one item (not sure if it's ok). And sometimes checkbox doubles all items (don't know why). If this issues is critical, I think you need to write custom ComboBox from scratch and this is serious work.

```
{
    SearchBox = new QComboBox(this);
    SearchBox->setEditable(true);

    QStringList Items;
    Items << "hi" << "bye";
    StringListModel = new QStringListModel();
    StringListModel->setStringList(Items);

    ProxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel;
    ProxyModel->setSourceModel(StringListModel);
    ProxyModel->setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    SearchBox->setModel(ProxyModel);

    // Check count again
    int count = SearchBox->count();    // count = 2

    // Try adding new entries
    QStringList Items_ = StringListModel->stringList();
    Items_ << "hi again";
    StringListModel->setStringList(Items_);

    count = SearchBox->count();    // count = 3

    Completer = new QCompleter(ProxyModel,this);
    Completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
    SearchBox->setCompleter(Completer);

    QObject::connect(SearchBox->lineEdit(), SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString)), this, SLOT(onTextChanged(QString)));
    QObject::connect(Completer, SIGNAL(activated(const QString &)), this, SLOT(onCompleterActivated(const QString &)));
}

void MainWindow::onTextChanged(QString Text) {
    QStringList Items = StringListModel->stringList();
    QString Item;
    foreach(Item,Items) {
        if (Item.indexOf(Text) > -1) {
            ProxyModel->setFilterFixedString(Text);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me