# Filter a supplier_combo_box as user types, if the typed text matches anything in the combo box values. I use PyQt5 and python 3.11

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Sorry for the formatting, I am new in Python, but I know Cobol and Pascal. So some bad habits I picked up from there.

```
class FilterComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FilterComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setEditable(True)

        # add a filter model to filter matching items
        self.pFilterModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        # add a completer, which uses the filter model
        self.completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
        # filter the completions
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QtWidgets.QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)

        # connect signals
        self.lineEdit().textEdited.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textEdited)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)

    def on_lineEdit_textEdited(self, text):
        regex = QtCore.QRegExp(".*" + text + ".*", QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive, QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterRegExp(regex)

    # on selection of an item from the completer, select the corresponding item from combobox 
    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        if text:
            index = self.findText(text)
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)
            self.activated[str].emit(self.itemText(index))

    # on model change, update the models of the filter and the completer as well 
    def setModel(self, model):
        super(FilterComboBox, self).setModel(model)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(model)
        self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)

    # on model column change, update the model column of the filter and completer as well
    def setModelColumn(self, column):
        self.completer.setCompletionColumn(column)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn(column)
        super(FilterComboBox, self).setModelColumn(column)
```

Works if the typed text matches the beginning of the values in the list of combo box items. But doesn't filter if it matches anything inside the string.

Comment: It seems like you've taken your code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4827207), which works as expected. Why don't you do what those answers suggest (using `setFilterFixedString`)?

Comment: I create my combo box like this:                       ''' # Create a label and a combo box
        supplier_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Supplier:")
        supplier_combo_box = FilterComboBox()
        supplier_combo_box.addItems(['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'John Smith', 'Jane Smith'])

Comment: Please don't try to use comments to post code blocks. Instead, [edit] your question and include a valid [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I modified my class to work with the combo box

```
class FilterComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FilterComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setEditable(True)

        # add a filter model to filter matching items
        self.pFilterModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        # add a completer, which uses the filter model
        self.completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
        # always show all (filtered) completions
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QtWidgets.QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)

        # connect signals
        self.lineEdit().textEdited.connect(self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)

    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        if text:
            index = self.findText(text)
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)
            self.activated[str].emit(self.itemText(index))
```

I create my combo box like this

```
        # Create a label and a combo box
        supplier_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Supplier:")
        supplier_combo_box = FilterComboBox()
        supplier_combo_box.addItems(['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'John Smith', 'Jane Smith'])
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**